# C# asp.net mvc Username regex

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc

Im looking for regex for usernames

I want to allow:

- only ASCII
- only - _ symbols
- minium 5 characters and maximum 15

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you go

```
^[-0-9A-Za-z_]{5,15}$
```

Note that the - is put first in the character class otherwise it will get the meaning of indicating a range as in 0-9 = 0 to 9